# LoRa power level contradictions

Tags: power, rf, lora

I've got some LoRa boards that claim 20 dBm transmit power. They do indeed show ~100 mW output power on an old-school moving-coil RF wattmeter.

However, on a spectrum analyser with 20dB + 30dB attenuators inline the ~1 s long transmit hill peaks at -74 dBm which means the Tx power must be -24 dBm, which is probably why I don't see any RF fuzz on a CRO (5 mV scale) across the 50 Ω dummy load.

I can't figure out this contradiction between the label/wattmeter result and the CRO/spectrum analyser result. Is there something about LoRa chirping I'm missing?

Comment: Which LoRa band are you using? Maximum power on the 868MHz band is 20mW ERP.

Comment: The 915 band with tx_power_level set to 14